# knockout custom binding for slick js not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, slick.js, ko-custom-binding

My working code without knockout binding is :

```
<div class="slick_demo_1">

                    <div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <h2>Slide 1</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <h2>Slide 2</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <h2>Slide 3</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And to initiallize slick my js code is:

```
$('.slick_demo_1').slick({
                dots: true
            });
```

The code above is working fine. 
Now the code with knockout binding is:

```
<div class="slick_demo_1" data-bind="foreach:showSlider">

                    <div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <h2 data-bind="slider"></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And to bind slick with DOM my code is:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slick = { 
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                $(element).slick({
                    dots: true
                });
            }
        };
```

But the custom binding is not working. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you're showing hardly resembles the correct implementation of a custom binder.

Several hints:

- you should use the custom binding in the root element
- the custom binding should take care of building, and, if possible, removing the carousel API from the element (using slick's `destroy` or `unslick`) if the element is disposed of by ko
- the custom binder should be able to update the elements inside the carousel
- it would be interesting to use an additional `slickOptions` binding to pass additional objects to the slick initialization

The basic structure of a custom binding [is explained here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). See the code template:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
    // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
},
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
    // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
    // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
}
```

};

As explained, the `init` is responsible of initializing the caroulse, and the `update` is responsible of updating the content of the carousel when the array changes. R P Niemeyer makes an in depth explanation of custom binding here: [Another Look at Custom Bindings for KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html).

If you implement it correctly, your HTML code should look something like this:

```
<div data-bind="slick: imagesArray, slickOptions: additionalOptions>
</div>
```

On the `init`, your custom binding should create the elements based on the `imagesArray`, and call the slick initialization, using the `additionalOptions` if present, and register the slick destruction when the element is disposed of by ko. In the update you should modify the inner elements and possible reapply slick. You should also review [slick's API](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick).

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/sktspj1w/) shows a partial implementation, but more complete that the current the floowing snippet:

```js
var imageUrls = [];
var i = 1;
for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
    imageUrls.push('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/'+i);

ko.bindingHandlers.slick = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // Clears the div
        $(element).empty();
        // Creates the inner divs with images
        var images = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        if (images) {
         images.forEach(function(imgUrl) {
                $div = $('<div>');
                $image = $('<img>');
                $image.attr('src',imgUrl);
                $div.append($image);
                $(element).append($div)
            });
        }

        // try to recover slickOptions
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().slickOptions || {};

        // Initialize slick on the div, with provided options
        $(element).slick(options);

        //handle disposal, if KO removes the element
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).slick('unslick');
        });
    },
    //update the control when the view model changes
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var images = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        // Do something to update the content
    }
};


var vm = {
    images: ko.observableArray(imageUrls),
    options: {}
}

ko.applyBindings(vm, gallery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.8/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.8/slick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.8/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="gallery" 
     style="width:400px"
     data-bind="slick: images, slickOptions: {dots:true, initialSlide:4}">
</div>
```

The missing part in the implementation is the updating of the gallery if the imgUrls changes. But it shows the main techniques in the hints.